# Uncaught TypeError: Object has no method ... Javascript

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, typeerror

I'm having an issue where I get an error that says...

> "Uncaught TypeError: Object f771b328ab06 has no method 'addLocation'"

I'm really not sure what's causing this. The `'f771b328ab06'` is a user ID in the error. I can add a new user and prevent users from being duplicated, but when I try to add their location to the list, I get this error.

Does anybody see what's going wrong? The error occurs in the `else` statement of the initialize function as well (if the user ID exists, just append the location and do not create a new user). I have some notes in the code, and I'm pretty sure that this is partly due to how I have modified an example provided by another user.

```
function User(id) {
    this.id = id;

    this.locations = [];

    this.getId = function() {
        return this.id;
    };
    this.addLocation = function(latitude, longitude) {
        this.locations[this.locations.length] = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);
        alert("User ID:" );
};
    this.lastLocation = function() {
        return this.locations[this.locations.length - 1];
    };
    this.removeLastLocation = function() {
        return this.locations.pop();
    };
}

function Users() {
    this.users = {};

     //this.generateId = function() { //I have omitted this section since I send
        //return Math.random();       //an ID from the Android app. This is part of
    //};                              //the problem.

    this.createUser = function(id) {
        this.users[id] = new User(id);
        return this.users[id];
    };
    this.getUser = function(id) {
        return this.users[id];
    };
    this.removeUser = function(id) {
        var user = this.getUser(id);
        delete this.users[id];

        return user;
    };
}

var users = new Users();

function initialize() { 
    alert("Start");
    $.ajax({                                      
        url: 'api.php',                                               
        dataType: 'json',                   
        success: function(data){
            var user_id = data[0];
            var latitude = data[1];
            var longitude = data[2];

            if (typeof users.users[user_id] === 'undefined') {
                users.createUser(user_id);
                users.users[user_id] = "1";
                user_id.addLocation(latitude, longitude); // this is where the error occurs
            }           
            else {
                user_id.addLocation(latitude, longitude); //here too
                alert(latitude);
            }
        }   
    })      
}
setInterval(initialize, 1000);
```

Since I get the ID from the phone and do not need to generate it here (only receive it), I commented out the part that creates the random ID. In doing this, I had to add a parameter to the `createUser` method within `Users()` so that I can pass the ID as an argument from `Initialize()`. See the changes to `createUser` below:

Before, with the generated ID (the part where the number is generated is in the above code block with comments):

```
this.createUser = function() {
    var id = this.generateId();
    this.users[id] = new User(id);
    return this.users[id];
};
```

After, with the ID passed as an argument:

```
this.createUser = function(id) { 
    this.users[id] = new User(id);
    return this.users[id];
};
```

If anyone has any suggestions I would really appreciate it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you're getting user_id by :

```
var user_id = data[0];
```

So it's a part of the json answer : maybe a string or another dictionnary, this can't be a user object. You should try to update your code in your success function inside the "if" block by :

```
user = users.createUser(user_id);

//The following line is a non sense for me you put an int inside 
//an internal structure of your class that should contain object
//users.users[user_id] = "1"; 

user.addLocation(latitude, longitude);
```

Comment: Well, I'm new to JS and I just wanted to be able to search the keys to prevent IDs from being duplicated. I put the "1" there just as a placeholder. Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: I got it figured out. I didn't have user defined in the if statment. Oops. I commented out the `users.users[user_id] = "1";` section and it seems to be working fine. Thanks for the insight.

Comment: If you're new checkout Firebug, it might really help you to debug your code.